# Pourquoi « en lire » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, en

Dans cette phrase :

> J'ai déjà lu certains romans de cet écrivain et je ne veux pas en lire
>   d'autres.

Pourquoi on doit utiliser « en » et avant « lire » ? Est-ce qu'il y a une règle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*En* est un pronom personnel 3<sup>e</sup> personne du singulier. Il peut être complément d'objet direct (COD) ou complément d'objet indirect (COI) ou complément de lieu.

Dans l'exemple que tu donnes il est COD. Il remplace « romans de cet écrivain ».

Dans la phrase suivante il est COI de lire :

> Je n'ai pas lu le nouveau roman de Duduche mais on m'en a parlé.

Et dans ce dernier exemple il est complément de lieu :

> Es-tu passé à la poste ? Oui, j'en viens.

**Attention à sa place** : il se place entre le sujet et le verbe.

[La liste des pronoms personnels en français](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-2799.php).

On classe souvent les [pronoms personnels *en* et *y*](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/20/grammaire/573.html) ensemble car ils présentent un certains de points communs.

Comment: Ouiii! Tu as raison! Je connais ce pronom mais certains fois je ne me le rappelle pas... Merci beaucoup :D

Answer (score 4):

**En** remplace  **romans de cet écrivain** pour éviter la répétition, mais si tu veux tu peux écrire :

> J'ai déjà lu certains romans de cet écrivain et je ne veux pas lire d'autres romans de cet écrivain.

On appelle ça la substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Je crois que dans cette constuctions *en [...] d'autres*, on a un **en redondant lexicalisé** (Grevisse, Bon usage, 14e éd., §680), du même genre que l'on retrouve dans certaines expression comme *en avoir assez de* ou *c'en est fait de*. En effet, la présence du pronom *en* devrait normalement interdire la présence de *d'autres* qui est techniquement son référent.